# How to differentiate the function, $7x^5\sqrt{3x^4-5x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factoring, chain-rule

$f'(x)= 7x^5(3x^4-5x^2)^{1/2}$

$= 35x^4(3x^4-5x^2)^{-1/2} +1/2(3x^4-5x^2)^{-1/2}(12x^3-10x)(7x^5)$

$= 35x^4(3x^4-5x^2)^{-1/2} + 1/2 (12x^3-10x)(7x^5)$

That is what I have done so far using the product rule and the chain rule. However, I don't know how to move forward. I also apologize for the horrible format but I really don't know how to code it nicely.

Comment: a * f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)

Comment: Here's a starting point to deal with the "horrible format": http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Well, there is nothing to move forward to. What you wrote can be called a correct answer.

Comment: chain rule is used for composite functionsAlso, the final answer is incorrect

Comment: Can you spot the error on line 2? The error on line 3? Aside from that, any further manipulation of the answer is mainly a matter of taste, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Given that

$f(x) = 7 x^5 \sqrt{3 x^4 - 5 x^2}$

Using the product rule, we find:

$f'(x) = 7 (5 x^4) \sqrt{3 x^4 - 5 x^2} + 7 x^5
\left( {1 \over 2 \sqrt{3 x^4 - 5 x^2}} (12 x^3 - 10 x)        \right)$

Simplifying, we get

$f'(x) = 35 x^4 \sqrt{3 x^4 - 5 x^2} + {7 x^6 (6 x^2 - 5) \over \sqrt{3 x^4 - 5 x^2}}$

The answer can be further simplified as follows:

$
f'(x) = 35 x^5 \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5} + 
{ 7 x^5 (6 x^2 - 5) \over \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5} } $

i.e.

$
f'(x) = { 35 x^5 (3 x^2 - 5) + 7 x^5 (6 x^2 - 5) 
 \over \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5}} =
{7 x^5 (15 x^2 - 25 + 6 x^2 - 5) \over \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5}} = {7 x^5 (21 x^2 - 30) \over \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5}}
$

Further simplifying, we arrive at

$
f'(x) = {21 x^5 (7 x^2 - 10) \over \sqrt{3 x^2 - 5}}
$

Comment: Can you show me how to do it using both the chain rule and the product rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a bit as follows:

$$f(x)=7x^5\sqrt{3x^4-5x^2}=7x^6(3x^2-5)^{1/2}$$

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x)&=&42x^5(3x^2-5)^{1/2}+7x^6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(3x^2-5)^{-1/2}(6x)\\
&=&7x^5[6(3x^2-5)^{1/2}+3x^2(3x^2-5)^{-1/2}]\\
&=&7x^5(3x^2-5)^{-1/2}[6(3x^2-5)+3x^2]\\
&=&\frac{7x^5(21x^2-30)}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}\\
&=&\frac{21x^5(7x^2-10)}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Often when you have products, its beneficial to take a log first and then take derivates. So,

if $f(x)=x^5(3x^4-5x^2)^{0.5}$, then $k(x)= \log f(x)= 5\log x+0.5\log(3x^4-5x^2)$. Hence, $k'(x)= f'/f=5/x+0.5\frac{12x^3-10x}{3x^4-5x^2}$, which leads to $$f'=k'.f=x^5(3x^4-5x^2)^{0.5}\left(5/x+0.5\frac{12x^3-10x}{3x^4-5x^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&7x^{5}\sqrt{3x^4-5x^2}\\
f(x)&=&7x^{5}\sqrt{x^2(3x^2-5)}\\
f(x)&=&7x^{5}x\sqrt{3x^2-5}\\
f(x)&=&7x^{6}\sqrt{3x^2-5}\\
\dfrac{1}{7}f^{'}(x)&=&x^6\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}6x+6x^5\sqrt{3x^2-5}\\
\dfrac{1}{7\cdot6x^5}f^{'}(x)&=&\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3x^2-5}}x^2+\sqrt{3x^2-5}\\
\dfrac{1}{7\cdot6x^5}f^{'}(x)&=&\dfrac{x^2+2(3x^2-5)}{2\sqrt{3x^2-5}}\\
\dfrac{1}{7\cdot3x^5}f^{'}(x)&=&\dfrac{7x^2-10}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}\\
f^{'}(x)&=&\dfrac{21x^5(7x^2-10)}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: From the formatting of the question, it seems as if OP is asking for $f_1$. You may want to change the content of your answer.

Comment: Yeah, they formulatted it a bit better since it was posted. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one (to avoid product rule):
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=7\sqrt{3x^{14}-5x^{12}}\\
\text{hence}\\
f'(x)&=7\frac{42x^{13}-60x^{11}}{2\sqrt{3x^{14}-5x^{12}}}\\
&=21\frac{x^{11}(7x^2-10)}{x^6\sqrt{3x^2-5}}\\
&=21x^5\frac{7x^2-10}{\sqrt{3x^2-5}}.
\end{align}$$